# How to check if my Queue (Service Broker) is enable or not?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, service-broker

rarely, for reasons that have not yet identified, my queue is disabled, when this happend, I enable again with this query:

```
  ALTER QUEUE [MyQueue] WITH STATUS = ON;
```

but, i want to know when the queue is disabled, such as an event (T-SQL), or check each "x" time if queue is enabled.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Look into [`sys.service_queues`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187795.aspx):

```
select is_receive_enabled
from sys.service_queues
where name = N'MyQueue';
```

Your queue gets disabled by the [poison message handling mechanism](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171592(v=sql.105).aspx). When this happens an event is fired which can be captured via Event Notification, see [Service Broker Application Queue Disable Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468392/service-broker-application-queue-disable-event).